# Launching command line works from linqpad, doesn't work from my executable

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, .net-4.5

I'm facing a really weird issue, i'm trying to launch a command from a program with the following code, it works in linqpad, if i copy paste the EXACT same code in a standalone .exe it no longer works:

```
var cmd = "/K convert \"c:\\TesseractInput\\46a8c74d-ead1-4a6a-987f-a46b146cb58b.png\" \"c:\\TesseractOutput\\46a8c74d-ead1-4a6a-987f-a46b146cb58b.tif\"";
var proc = Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd);
proc.WaitForExit(20000);
```

In linqpad i end up with a command prompt and my command correctly executed. In my standalone exe i end up with a command promt with an error stating

```
Invalid Parameter - "c:\TesseractOutput\46a8c74d-ead1-4a6a-987f-a46b146cb58b.tif"
```

This is NOT specific to the program i'm calling (getting the same issue with other command line programs)

If i inspect the processes with sysinternal's processexplorer i see the cmd.exe is launched with the correct passed arguments while the one launched from my program gives path "error opening process".

Both linqpad and my exe run as the same user (myself, administrator)

I looked into this for quite a while and am not making any progress, any advice is most welcome as this is blocking for a deployment (last step was merging the external Tools dev i did in linqpad into my program)

update: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaand without changing anything it now . . . works.
Any clue what could have caused this?

Comment: @paqogomez It's why i stated it works in one and not the other, it's unlikely to be a quote issue since it's the SAME code in both case (so the issue would appear in both cases).

Comment: @paqogomez also which quote doesn't seem escaped well? it looks fine to me

Comment: Try removing the quotes around parameters that do not require them. I.E. Any parameter that does not have spaces. You do not need the quotes around either of the paths.

Comment: In Process.StartInfo, try turning on or off the UseShellExecute property.

Comment: @Mikanikal i don't need them in this trivial sample, but i do need them generally, also if you read it's the SAME sample with the SAME quotes thus that works in one case and not the other

Comment: @Ronan Thibaudau I understand the need and I'm glad you got a working answer. My suggestion was because I had a weird case one time that calling regasm.exe from a command prompt failed to find the .dll when the path had quotes even though there were no spaces. I got rid of the quotes and it found the .dll. To this day I couldn't explain it but it sticks with me as a troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command prompts can run as different users and they can run with different path environment variables - the path environment variable is where windows searches for the convert.exe; typically it checks the current folder and then it checks the folders in your path statement . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) I dont' have your convert program, but when I ran the below I got the same error.

```
C:\Users\user1>convert c:\temp\1.png c:\temp\2.tif
Invalid Parameter - c:\temp\2.tif

C:\Users\user1>convert /?
Converts a FAT volume to NTFS.

CONVERT volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:filename] [/NoSecurity] [/X]


  volume      Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
              mount point, or volume name.
  /FS:NTFS    Specifies that the volume will be converted to NTFS.
  /V          Specifies that Convert will be run in verbose mode.
  /CvtArea:filename
              Specifies a contiguous file in the root directory
              that will be the place holder for NTFS system files.
  /NoSecurity Specifies that the security settings on the converted
              files and directories allow access by all users.
  /X          Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
              All open handles to the volume will not be valid.

C:\Users\user1>
```

Comment: Does seem to be the issue however i'm really surpsized as 1) both are run as the same user and 2) neither linqpad nor my app have the exe in their folder (it's just added to the path by the installer)